# Android Button Click not go through, but action still take place

Tags: android, button, onclick

I want when a button is pressed in my activity, for the click not to occur (such as clickEnabled being false) but I want the action that would have occurred to still happen.

For example, say I have a Dialer application:

When button "One" is pressed, the user will not see that the button was actually clicked, but the action of adding a 1 to the edittext will still occur. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a selector as your button's background.and most important is samecolor no matter that is click , touch or idle . So through this ,you fake a no click effect.

And same time ,you can also add a click listener to this button to get the click event.

Hope that give you some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply use `onTouchListener` event for buttons instead of `onclickListener`

Comment: `onTouchListener()` on the button will not be invoked if the button has `android:enabled="false"`

Comment: When `android:enabled=false` is set no events has been fired. He/she just gives an opinion I think. In given dialer example he/she want to take action even user click wasn't complete.

Comment: as Saeed said, I want when the button is fired, no click is performed (specifically on that the user can see) but the action is still performed as before.